# How can I design UI in IONIC as shown in the image sample?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to design a UI as shown in the image but I am confused whether I should use ion-segment or tabs to design the same. Pls help me with this and also if possible pls provide CSS, I will be thankful!

Edit: I am able to design cards using grid but I want to design sidebar with functionality.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS Grid properties to achieve such UI, it really makes our life easier. Learn. try and experiment the things. You'll be easily able to attain such UI.

I have attached some useful references below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zBsdzdE4sM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I am able to design cards using grid but I want to design sidebar with functionality.